# Sum over binary words of length $k$.

Tags: probability, complex-numbers, summation, combinatorics-on-words

Let $w$ be a word of length $k$ on binary alphabet$\{0,1\}$ with $p(0)=p$,  $p(1)=q$, and $p>q$. How would you calculate this sum? (exact or up to the first order)
$$\sum_{w,w^{'}}(p(w)+p(w^{'})-p(w)p(w^{'}))^{-s}$$

Where $s$ is a complex number.

Comment: $p(0)$ is the probability of getting a $0$? Do you sum over all the possible couple of words?  Thanks

Comment: @MaxFt Yes, $p(0)$ is the probability of getting a 0. And yes, the sum is over all the possible couple of words of length $k$.

Comment: So do you assume that $p + q = 1$?